# Silex 2: Performance. Are these good performance metrics?

Tags: php, performance, silex

I have started a small project using Silex framework. I have used [the skeleton proposed by Fabien](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-Skeleton).

I have registered these stuff:

- ServiceControllerServiceProvider
- HttpFragmentServiceProvider
- SessionServiceProvider
- LocaleServiceProvider
- TranslationServiceProvider
- MonologServiceProvider
- AssetServiceProvider
- TwigServiceProvider
- DoctrineServiceProvider
- DerAlex\Pimple\YamlConfigServiceProvider
- Pmaxs\Silex\Locale\Provider\LocaleServiceProvider

I have defined the before and after middleware, I have routed a couple of controllers, and finally I have specify the firewall.

In order to test the performance, I have created a simple page with 4 simple SQL sentences and with a very trivial template.

I am using an Ubuntu 15 with PHP7 and OPCache. The hardware is an Intel i5 third generation with 8GB RAM.

I am concerned with the time used in load the page, because it is about 0.9 seconds in develop mode, and from my point of view it is too heavy.

[image: Performance metrics]

Can anybody explain me this graphic?

Can you give any advise about how I can improve this load time?

If I look the times using the Firebug, I get:
Development mode: 827ms
Production mode: 1720ms

[image: Production time]
[image: Development time]

How is it possible that production mode is slower than development mode?

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATED / ADDED TWO NEW SCREENSHOTS.**

Profiler for dev mode:

[image: Profiler for dev mode]

Profiler for prod mode:

[image: Profiler for prod mode]

Comment: You should not use dev environment to test performance. Due to design, silex uses compiled cache (routing, twig templates, etc) to work. In dev environment cache is being recreated on each request, so that's the reason you're getting such result. But it uses precompiled cache in prod environment, so performance should be a way better there.

Comment: @evgeny-soynov. Thanks for your answer. I agree with you. But if you look my times, the prod enviroment time is double than dev enviroment. I don't understand this. I would also like to know if that times are correct or not. Thanks again.

Comment: Metrics for my project: ~400ms dev, ~100ms production (php 5.6). Add screenshots of web profiler for dev and not dev to compare. Most time takes closure, I think it is before middleware.

Comment: I agree with you, your times are good times. Why my prod time is double than dev? I don't understand.

Comment: Add 2 screenshots of web profiler for dev and not dev to compare.

Comment: @max-p : I just add two new screenshots. Thanks.

Comment: And the most important question - is this php-fpm and nginx or Apache with mod_php? For comparison - I use Lumen (which is also a micro framework) and for slightly more complex request I'm getting responses back within 30-40 msec (on PHP 5.6 with xdebug). Edit: I'm not suggesting a framework swap, I'm enquiring about the infrastructure.

Comment: Before middleware takes more time in not dev mode. May be some functions are disabled in middleware in dev mode.. Show code of this middleware

Comment: @max-p: I am using a virtual machine deployed with vagrant. The hardware (host) is i3 (3rd generation) with 8GB RAM, and the virtual machine has 4GB RAM and 2 CPUs. The SO is ubuntu/trusty64, and I am using Apache2 with mod_php (php7). I know that main time is because of before middleware (it only has 4 SQL simple queries). And I guess that average time is because of I am using a virtual machine on my Windows 8. But... why prod time is double than dev time? It is very stranger.

Comment: Apache with mod_php is the cause. Swapping to nginx + fpm would yield incredible performance. You don't have to trust me, but at best you'll achieve minimal performance dabbling with code optimization for Silex.

Comment: @mjh : Thanks very much for the information and for your time. I am using Apache + mod_php only in my dev enviroment. I know that nginx + fpm is better and faster. But I would like to know why the prod times are slower than dev times. Because I guess that using Apache + mod_php the prod time should be minor (or equal) than dev time. Thanks again!

Comment: There's only one thing that pops to my mind - you're dealing with SQL and you didn't specify how this SQL connection is established. My assumption is that you're running a slower HDD on the production environment and that your SQL RDBMS isn't set up properly to utilize resources as good as possible. Also, are you using persistent connections?

Comment: @mjh : About the hardware, it is the same for dev and prod environment. I am not using persistent connections. At the moment, it remains a mystery because prod time is double that of dev.

Comment: I guess the problem is because of the hardware. I have changed the server and now dev time is lower than prod time. I believe the old filesystem cache is slower than if it is not used. In the new server the file system must be higher, so now the silex prod cache is faster that if it is not used (dev mode).